# Lightning Components go crazy with errors and CPU when Debug Mode on

Tags: lightning-aura-components, debugging, platform-bug

When I enable the Debug Mode for Lightning components in the Setup most of my Lightning components literally go crazy. They bombard me with cryptic erros like that and after a while my Chrome brings my CPU close to a halt.

> Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'foo' of component
>   'markup://aura:iteration {24974:0}' is not visible to ...

[image]

I'm quite sure that this is not related to my tested clean JS code so I assume it's a bug.

**Did you see those symptoms as well? Do you know of a Known (documented) issue?**

Comment: I have just turned on debug mode and tested my lightning components (plenty of them)  - all looks fine in my sandbox